# Band Periodicity

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

this is one of sounds features and it has been used in some AI voice app.
"The periodicity property of each sub-band is represented by the maximum
local peak of the normalized correlation function."

I can't understand the way to calculate it, any help will be appreciated 
any law to find "normalized correlation" and  "maximum local peak" .
in my law i cant understand what "s(n)" value.
I need a "s(n)" explanation so i can build a function using matlab , or a clearer law..
please if u don't have an idea about band periodicity don't try to searcher about it,there is nothing on the internet!
 [image: I found these laws in a research paper but i can't understand "s(n)"]

Comment: This might be better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

s(n) is just the sample at index n of the signal **after** bandpass filtering.